# Extrair os produtos de um XML de NFe

Tags: java, xml

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java que vou precisar extrair os dados do XML da NFe,

Extrair alguns dados eu consigo mapeando as Tags como destinatário emitente entre outros.

Mas quando preciso extrair os produtos da NFe não consigo.

Segue abaixo o um trecho de produtos de um XML da NFe.

nfe.xml

```
<det nItem="1">
    <prod>
      <cProd>121402233</cProd>
      <cEAN>7898950236241</cEAN>
      <xProd>Michaelis Dicionario Escolar Da Lingua Portuguesa 1a Ed</xProd>
      <NCM>49019900</NCM>
      <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
      <uCom>PC</uCom>
      <qCom>1</qCom>
      <vUnCom>32.90</vUnCom>
      <vProd>32.90</vProd>
      <cEANTrib>7898950236241</cEANTrib>
      <uTrib>PC</uTrib>
      <qTrib>1</qTrib>
      <vUnTrib>32.90</vUnTrib>
      <vFrete>3.95</vFrete>
      <vDesc>3.95</vDesc>
      <indTot>1</indTot>
    </prod>
    <imposto>
      <ICMS>
        <ICMS40>
          <orig>0</orig>
          <CST>40</CST>
        </ICMS40>
      </ICMS>
      <PIS>
        <PISNT>
          <CST>06</CST>
        </PISNT>
      </PIS>
      <COFINS>
        <COFINSNT>
          <CST>06</CST>
        </COFINSNT>
      </COFINS>
    </imposto>
    <infAdProd>Desconto Incondicional Concedido: R$ 3.95</infAdProd>
  </det>
```

Abaixo segue trecho do código que faz a leitura de um campo(Tag) da NFe.

LeituraXml.java

```
public class LeituraXml {

private SAXBuilder sb;
private Document d;
private Element nfe;

public LeituraXml(String arquivo) {

    try {
        sb = new SAXBuilder();
        d = sb.build(new File(arquivo));
        nfe = d.getRootElement();


    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exceção ao processar arquivo! " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public String getNumeroNFe() {
    try {

        XPath nNF = XPath.newInstance("//k:nfeProc/k:NFe/k:infNFe/k:ide/k:nNF");
        nNF.addNamespace("k", d.getRootElement().getNamespaceURI());
        Element node = (Element) nNF.selectSingleNode(d.getRootElement());

        return node.getText();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao processar arquivo! " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para extrair os dados da NFE utilizei uma outra forma diferente da que descrevi acima.

1º Baixei os arquivos de layout da NFE no site na parte Esquemas XML [Site NFE Fazenda](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/listaConteudo.aspx?tipoConteudo=/fwLvLUSmU8=) fiz o processo de transformação dos arquivos XSD para XML e coloquei em um diretório do meu projeto.

Após isso realizei o processo de leitura dos dados da NFE da seguinte forma:

EntradaXML.java

```
....
   public void LerXml(String xml) {


    // Caminho do arquivo XML da NFe
    String xmlFilePathNFe3 = xml;
    JAXBContext context = null;
    TNfeProc tNfeProc = null;

    try {
        // Realizando o parser do XML da NFe para Objeto Java
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TNfeProc.class.getPackage().getName());

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller1 = context.createUnmarshaller();

        // Este é o seu Objeto Java da NFe (tNfeProc)
        tNfeProc = (TNfeProc) unmarshaller1.unmarshal(new File(xmlFilePathNFe3));

    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TelaCompra.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

     for (TNFe.InfNFe.Det item : tNfeProc.getNFe().getInfNFe().getDet()) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item.getProd().getCProd());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item.getProd().getXProd());

    }
  }
 ...
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo de fazer o processo de transformação dos arquivos XSD para XML?